# java protocol buffers - construct sub message with extension field

Tags: java, protocol-buffers

How do we construct a sub message by adding the extension field in protocol buffers. In C++, one way of doing it is by using MutableMessage(Message, FieldDescriptor) with reflection interface. How do we do the similar thing in Java?

I'm a newbie so don't know a lot about protocol buffers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following from jonathons answer, here is and example of creating and accessing extensions in java

Protobuf definition:

```
message Message
{
    extensions 100 to max;

    required uint64 A = 1;
}

message Event
{
    extend Message { 
        required Event ext = 101; 
        optional string name = 102;
    }

    extensions 100 to max;

    required uint64 B = 1;

}
```

Using the extension:

```
Extension01.Message.Builder bm = Extension01.Message.newBuilder();
Extension01.Message.Builder bm1 = Extension01.Message.newBuilder();
Extension01.Event.Builder be = Extension01.Event.newBuilder();
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(extFileOut);

be.setB(5678);


bm.setA(123);
bm.setExtension(Extension01.Event.ext, be.build()); // set the extension value

bm.build().writeDelimitedTo(out);
out.close();

FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(extFileOut);

ExtensionRegistry registry = ExtensionRegistry.newInstance(); // create extension registry
Extension01.registerAllExtensions(registry);  // Allocate the extensions 
bm1.mergeDelimitedFrom(in, registry);
in.close();

Event extension = bm1.getExtension(Extension01.Event.ext); // get the extension
if (extension == null) {
    System.out.println("No extension");
} else {
    System.out.println(extension.getB());
}
```

**Edit:**

```
Line setting extension value:

bm.setExtension(Extension01.Event.ext, be.build());
```

The variable **Extension01.Event.ext** is generated by protocol buffers and can be used get/put the values of extensions.

**Edit 2:**

This is how I think extensionInfo is used (I have not tried it my self):

```
ExtensionInfo extensionInfo = registry.findExtensionByNumber(..., 101);
bm1.getField(extensionInfo.descriptor);
bm1.setField(extensionInfo.descriptor, value)
```

Comment: I'm not able to understand it fully. Referring your solution + protobuf javadocs, I was able to get extensioninfo by using the given extension number (I used registerAllExtensions() and findExtensionByNumber() for that). However, I need to use setExtension() now to generate a message with embedded extension, which needs GeneratedExtension as one of the parameters. Do you know how to use extensioninfo to set extension? Or am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: See the bm.setExtension line in the example above

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm still not getting it fully. Where does your solution refer any ExtensionInfo object which can be used in setExtension() method? All I see you using setExtension() with first param being extension identifier and second param being the value built from extension.

Comment: The variable Extension01.Event.ext which was generated by protocol buffers can be used to set and retrieve the values of extensions.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. Thank you for clarifying though. What I'm asking is if there is a way to get Extension01.Event.ext (extension identifier) from extension number (101).

Comment: For generated messages it does not really work that way. There is a getExtensionByName method on the registry-class, then use the descriptor variable in the getField?? method; take a bit of fiddling. Alternatively DynamicMessage's allow retrieval by number but with DynamicMessages you do not have Generated-Protocol buffers

Comment: Yes, you are right. I did try the stuff that I have mentioned in my very first comment, however, it returns me ExtensionInfo instance while invoking findExtenionByNumber(). So have been trying to figure out how to convert that into the identifier so I can pass that into setExtension() method :)

Comment: I think you can use the extension var of ExtensionInfo in the getField and setField methods of message. I have not tried it myself but if you look at code for getField/setField the first thing it does is check if it is a extension field. I will add a bit more to my answer

Answer (score 3):

Use the `setExtension` method.  Given:

```
message Bar {
  extend Foo {
    optional string foo_string = 1;
  }
}
```

You can build a Bar message as so:

```
Foo foo = Foo.newBuilder()
    .setExtension(Bar.fooString, "My foo string")
    .build();
```

See the [Java Generated Code documentation on extensions](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/java-generated#extension) for Protocol Buffers for more details.

Comment: Thanks. And how do I retrieve extension identifier from a given extension number?

Comment: Protocol Buffers generates a static final variable that can be used to access Extension classes